# import/no-unresolved error in current directory

Tags: javascript, eslint

I’m importing a module like this:

```js
import DatePicker from './DatePicker';
```

It’s obviously in the same directory, but I get the `import/no-unresolved` eslint error.

My eslint settings:

```js
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'app/javascript/components'],
      },
      webpack: {
        config: 'config/webpack/development.js',
      },
    },
  },
```

My components are in `/app/javascript/components`.

Why am I getting this error?